# Compute shader compilation fails but info log is empty

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, windows-subsystem-for-linux, glut

I'm trying to get OpenGL compute shader working but when I compile it but the compilation fails and OpenGL does not give me any info log.

The shader is super simple (I wanted to figure out whats wrong so I have changed it to super simple version that should work)

```c
#version 460 core

// for nvidia cards this should be 32 or a multiple of it
layout(local_size_x = 8, local_size_y = 4) in;

void main() {
    int x = 1;
}
```

and the cpp code:

```
compute = glCreateShader(GL_COMPUTE_SHADER);
glShaderSource(compute, 1, &code, NULL);
glCompileShader(compute);

glGetShaderiv(compute, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
if(!success)
{
    glGetShaderInfoLog(compute, 512, NULL, infoLog);
    std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::COMPUTE::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    return 1;
};

ID = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(ID, compute);
glLinkProgram(ID);

glGetProgramiv(ID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
if(!success)
{
    glGetProgramInfoLog(ID, 512, NULL, infoLog);
    std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
glDeleteShader(compute);
```

I am sure that the shader is properly read from the file (I cout it earlier). Additionally I noticed that when I had `glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)` instead of compute shader I did get info log:

```
0:4(1) : error: input layout qualifiers only valid in geometry, tessellation, fragment and compute shaders
0:4(1) : error: invalid input lavout qualifiers used
```

But since changing to `glCreateShader(GL_COMPUTE_SHADER)` I get no logs (even if I change the variable names inside layout to something obviously wrong)

I am working on Windows 11, WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 with Nvidia RTX 3080TI,

My OpenGL version is:

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Max core profile version: 4.6
    Max compat profile version: 4.6
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES [23] profile version: 3.0
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

My opengl context initialization looks like this:

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
// we need opengl 4.6 context for compute shaders
glutInitContextVersion( 4, 6 );
glutInitContextProfile( GLUT_CORE_PROFILE );
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE);
glutInitWindowSize(WORLD_WIDTH, WORLD_HEIGHT);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
glutCreateWindow("Hello World!");
glutDisplayFunc(renderScreen);
glutMotionFunc(motion);
glutIdleFunc(tick);

GLenum err = glewInit();
if (GLEW_OK != err)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error with initialising glew: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
}
```

Does anyone know why this might be the case and how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `compute`? Any changes it is zero? If so, what `glGetError()` returns right after the call to `glCreateShader()`? If it does return `GL_INVALID_ENUM`, then compute shaders may just be unsupported in your setup for some reason.

https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCreateShader.xhtml